# With Firebug i am able to see HTML<Div>section inside the parent, when i use Selenium to fetch the html source based <div id>, i cannot see the child

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, obiee

Using Firebug i am able to see the HTML  section inside the parent ,

```html
<div id="tabstop_1_ElementForTabStop" class="treeContainer" style="visibility: visible; height: 100%; overflow: auto;" tabindex="0">
  <div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
    <div id="tree1462947337992_children">
      <div id="tree1462947337992$virtual_root" class="treeNode">
        <div id="tree1462947337992$virtual_root_children" class="treeChildContainer" style="margin-left: 0px; display: block;">
          <div id="tree1462947337992$/users/npatel" class="treeNode" style="display: block;">
            <div id="tree1462947337992$/shared" class="treeNode" style="display: block;">
              <span class="masterTreeLine treeLine" style="display: block;">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/shared_children" class="treeChildContainer" style="display: block;">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/shared/Components" class="treeNode">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/shared/Sales Home" class="treeNode">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/shared/Sample Lite" class="treeNode">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/shared/Skill Portal" class="treeNode">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/shared/Trainings & Skills" class="treeNode">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

but when i use Selenium using Java to fetch the html source based on the parent , i cannot see the child section of the root div
Here is my selenium code snippet:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("tabstop_1_ElementForTabStop"));
 System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));

 Thread.sleep(4000);
 String x = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", ele);
 String div_id = x.substring(x.indexOf("id=\"tree") + 4, x.indexOf("_children\""));
 System.out.println(div_id);
 ele = driver.findElement(By.id(div_id + "$/shared_children"));
 System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("textContent"));
 System.out.println(jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent", ele));
```

Output of the above code gives this

> Single Select Tree. . Currently selected values are , Folder. My Folders. , , The cursor node is , , Available commands. Use the up and down arrow keys to move the node cursor. Use the right arrow to expand a subtree. Use the left arrow to close an expanded subtree. Use spacebar and enterkey to select values. Use home and end keys to move to the first or last node. My FoldersShared Folders
>   tree1462948179598

The Complete html source as extracted from firebug is below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" style="visibility: visible;">

<head>

  <body class="masterOBIEE HTMLBody">
    <div class="HeaderContainer">
      <a id="idSkipContentLink" class="HeaderSkipLink" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:saw.header.skipToContent()">Skip to content</a>
      <table class="masterBrandingArea HeaderTopBar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
        <div class="HeaderBarSeparator"></div>
        <table class="masterGlobalLayer HeaderSecondBar HeaderSecondBarPadding" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="HeaderTitleBarCell">
                <td class="HeaderNavBarCell">
                  <div align="right">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="HeaderAlerts">
                            <td class="HeaderNavMenubarCell">
                              <div class="HeaderMenubar" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td title="Home">
                                        <td>
                                          <td>
                                            <td>
                                              <td title="Favorites">
                                                <td>
                                                  <td title="Dashboards">
                                                    <span id="dashboard" class="masterMenuButton masterMenuButtonGlobal uberBarTextMenuButtonSpan" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-label="Dashboard drop down menu" tabindex="0">
<span class="HeaderMenuBarText HeaderMenuNavBarText" role="presentation">
<span role="presentation">Dashboards</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span class="HeaderMenuBarDropdown" role="presentation">
</span>
                                                  </td>
                                                  <td>
                                                    <td title="New">
                                                      <td>
                                                        <td title="Open">
                                                          <td>
                                                            <td>
                                                              <td title="npatel">
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </div>
                              </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="PageOuterBodyTopRightTd">
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      < form style = "position: absolute; top: -1000px; display:none;" >
        < script src = "/analytics/res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/b_mozilla/common/componentheader.js"
      type = "text/javascript" >
        < span id = "sawruler"
      style = "display:none;visibility:hidden;white-space:nowrap;" > < /span>
<div class="masterGlobalLayer ComponentHeader ComponentHeaderNoSecondaryTabbar">
<div id="idSummarySectionDiv" class="masterPrimaryLayer masterComponentHeaderSummaryDiv ComponentHeaderSummaryDiv">
<table class="masterPrimaryLayer ComponentHeaderTable ComponentHeaderTableEmptyUberbar ComponentHeaderTableEmptyTabBar ComponentHeaderTableSummary" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table class="masterPrimaryLayer PrimaryTabTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="PrimaryTabbarLeftBorder" style="width:4px"></td >
        < td >
        < div id = "PageContentOuterDiv"
      class = "masterSecondaryLayer PageContentOuterDiv PageContentBodyDiv CatalogPageContentOuterDiv"
      style = "height: 237px;" >
        < table cellspacing = "0"
      cellpadding = "0"
      border = "0"
      style = "width:100%;table-layout:fixed;" >
        < tbody >
        < tr >
        < td class = "SecondaryTabbarLeftBorder" > < /td>
<td style="width:100%">
<div id="idCatalog" style="height: 237px;">
<div id="idCatalogSplitter" class="SplitterContainer" style="overflow: hidden; visibility: inherit; width: 1326px; height: 235px;">
<div class="SplitterContentPane" sizeshare="220px" layouttype="contentPane" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 220px; height: 235px;">
<div id="idCatalogFoldersAccordion" class="masterAccordionBottomContentAreaPanel PrimaryAccordion" style="width: 220px; height: 232px;">
<div class="AccordionPane" panename="folders" maintainstate="true" expanded="true" style="display: block;">
<div class="masterAccordionHeader masterAccordionTopHeader AccordionFirstPaneHead" style="width: 218px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
<div class="masterAccordionContentAreaPanel AccordionPaneBody" style="width: 214px; height: 77px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; padding: 2px;">
<div id="tree1462947337992" style="overflow: hidden; width: 214px; height: 75px;">
<div id="tabstop_1_ElementForTabStop" class="treeContainer" style="visibility: visible; height: 100%; overflow: auto;" tabindex="0">
<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
<div id="tree1462947337992_children">
<div id="tree1462947337992$virtual_root" class="treeNode">
<div id="tree1462947337992$virtual_root_children" class="treeChildContainer" style="margin-left: 0px; display: block;">
<div id="tree1462947337992$/users / npatel " class="
      treeNode " style="
      display: block;
      ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared " class="
      treeNode " style="
      display: block;
      ">
<span class="
      masterTreeLine treeLine " style="
      display: block;
      ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared_children " class="
      treeChildContainer " style="
      display: block;
      ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared / Components " class="
      treeNode ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared / Sales Home " class="
      treeNode ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared / Sample Lite " class="
      treeNode ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared / Skill Portal " class="
      treeNode ">
<div id="
      tree1462947337992$ / shared / Trainings & Skills " class="
      treeNode ">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="
      overflow: auto;
      display: none;
      "></div>
<div style="
      overflow: auto;
      display: none;
      "></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="
      AccordionPane " sizeshare="
      170px " panename="
      tasks " maintainstate="
      true " expanded="
      true " style="
      display: block;
      ">
</div>
</div>
<div class="
      HorizSplitter " collapsenextpane="
      " layouttype="
      splitter " style="
      position: relative;
      top: -235px;
      left: 220px;
      width: 7px;
      height: 235px;
      ">
<div class="
      SplitterContentPane " layouttype="
      contentPane " style="
      position: relative;
      top: -470px;
      left: 229px;
      width: 1097px;
      height: 235px;
      ">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="
      SecondaryTabbarRightBorder "></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="
      0 " cellpadding="
      0 " style="
      width: 100 % ;
      table - layout: fixed;
      ">
</div>
</td>
<td class="
      PageOuterBodyCenterRight "></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="
      0 " cellpadding="
      0 " style="
      width: 100 % ;
      table - layout: fixed;
      ">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please help me on where i am going wrong or i am missing something?

Any lead will be very helpful**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you're asking honestly, but I do see what might be causing you some issue if you are expecting innerHTML and textContent to function correctly.

this line:

```
 System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Will almost never print anything because innerHTML is a property, not an attribute. Is it bound ONLY within the browser. Same goes for textContent, it is NOT and attribute, it is a property and is only present in the browser.

If you want the visible text of an element from WebDriver once you have located it, call:

```
ele.getText()
```

Which will give you the equivalent of the `textContent` property. As far as innerHTML, you really just have to execute the script the way you are now by calling `executeScript()` and using the "magic" arguments[] array to pass in the WebElement, then return the value of innerHTML. I have done this before and had no issue getting the HTML for all children as well.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, for the quick help. Yes i was going in wrong direction. I got the required html code with style= Display: hidden. 
What i did is:
1. As my target page url is having hidden divs, i made them visible by clicking on the Parent <div id>
2. Then iterating through to the child div to fetch my result using getText().

Answer (score 0):

Some of your HTML is not properly structured,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      < form style = "position: absolute; top: -1000px; display:none;" >
        < script src = "/analytics/res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/b_mozilla/common/componentheader.js"
      type = "text/javascript" >
```

Once I added closing tags for the opening `<script>` and `<form>` tags and changed the above to the HTML below, the `ele.getAttribute("innerHTML")` instruction returned the inner-html of that element.

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<form style = "position: absolute; top: -1000px; display:none;"></form>
<script src = "/analytics/res/v-0YH2UYTNo3k/b_mozilla/common/componentheader.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

Firebug might be more forgiving when it comes to incorrectly structured HTML.

Comment: Yes i guess Firebug does not bother about complete html tags, it just suuplies you set of ids, CSS Selectors and xpath help which we require in Selenium based interaction.
Thanks for bringing this into light, Cheers!!